# Pytest generate html in Docker container?

Tags: python, html, docker, containers, pytest

I'm trying to develop an application for web automation testing that generates a html report. It works locally but when trying to dockerize it I'm running into trouble.

Here's the most important line in the dockerfile (I think)

```
CMD ["pytest", "--html=report.html", "tests/test_your_info_page.py"]
```

The end goal is to have the testing started when a container is created. But the 'report.html' file doesn't seem to get generated

The rest of the docker file looks like this

```
FROM python:3.9 AS webautomation

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR .
COPY . .

CMD ["pytest", "--html=report.html", "tests/test_your_info_page.py"]

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=webautomation . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and requirements.txt looks like

```
pytest==6.2.2
selenium==3.141.0
pytest-html==3.1.1
```

Project Structure

```
-tests
      -test_your_info_page.py
```

Comment: Can you share your project structure? Is test_your_info_page.py under tests file?

Comment: I added a screenshot there. Hopefully that helps

Comment: First you need to specify which files you will copy not all. And if you use CMD or ENTRYPOINT they will run when container start. So you need to use RUN to create report file while building. But if it exit with error build fails.

Comment: I want it to run when a container is created. Not when building the docker image.

Comment: But when container start first step of dockerfile will not be there anymore. Only second part will run. So when you start your container you can not run cmd command in first section and use inside another. You need to use RUN to create report file while building.

Comment: Oh ok I think i understand what you're saying, Thank you. Is there a way I can have pytest run in the container, after creation or during creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the multistage builds. Removing `FROM nginx` I can now run pytest within the docker container.

UPDATE

using the docker `cp` command i could copy the report generated on my local machine and view it in browser